# aws cloudformation userdata: how to use local variable in script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing the cloudformation template that includes ec2 instance. In userdata block, I want to create a file with some content. In the file, I'm initializing local variable `MY_MESSAGE`, but next, after the template is deployed this variable is not shown in the file.

original temlate:

```
EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-03368e982f317ae48
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: ec2
      UserData:
        !Base64 |
        #!/bin/bash
        cat <<EOF > /etc/aws-kinesis/start.sh
        #!/bin/sh
        MY_MESSAGE="Hello World"
        echo $MY_MESSAGE
```

output file in ec2 instance:

```
#!/bin/sh
MY_MESSAGE="Hello World"
echo
```

As you can see variable `MY_MESSAGE` does not exist in echo block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `EOF` in quotes: `"EOF"`:

```
      UserData:
        !Base64 |
          #!/bin/bash
          cat <<"EOF" > /etc/aws-kinesis/start.sh
          #!/bin/sh
          MY_MESSAGE="Hello World"
          echo $MY_MESSAGE
          EOF
```